# Asyncapi allOf reusable schemas creates array instead of unified object in html rendering

Tags: asyncapi

I'm trying to write my first Asyncapi documentation file. I'd like to perform reusability of my schema between a reusableModel and others. However, the html documentation preview gives me an array with separate objects instead of one unified object. Here is my problematic yaml content:

```
asyncapi: 2.0.0
info:
  title: woaw
  version: 0.1.0
  description: >
    blabla
  license:
    name: UNLICENSED
defaultContentType: application/json
channels:
  myChannel:
    subscribe:
      message:
        oneOf:
          - $ref: '#/components/messages/new'
          - $ref: '#/components/messages/deleted'
          
components:
  messages:
    new:
      payload:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/new'
    deleted:
      payload:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/deleted'
        
  schemas:
    reusableModel:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
          format: uuid
          example: 37a2005e-70e6-4cf3-b7e3-19e087879e50
    new:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/reusableModel'
        - type: object
          properties:
            type:
              type: string
              enum: ["extension.new"]
            data:
              type: object
              properties:
                key1:
                  type: object
                  properties:
                    users:
                      type: array
                      items:
                        type: string
                        
    deleted:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/reusableModel'
        - type: object
          properties:
            type:
              type: string
              enum: ["extension.deleted"]
            data:
              type: object
              properties:
                key1:
                  type: string
```

You might copy/paste it to https://playground/asyncapi.io to see the rendering problem. The allOf object defined in the payload of the first messageType (new) appears as an array with in part 0 the reusableModel and in part 1 the rest of my properties (type + data) and not as unified object. The [documentation](https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/specifications/2.0.0#schema-object-examples) involves the following:

*The AsyncAPI Specification allows combining and extending model definitions using the allOf property of JSON Schema, in effect offering model composition. allOf takes in an array of object definitions that are validated independently but together compose a single object.*

I think I misunderstand some part of the documentation, can you explain to me ?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue from the generated documentation, inside the message payload section:

https://github.com/asyncapi/html-template/issues/11

Comment: As you found it is a known problem with the html-template, and as far as I can see your document looks fine and you have not misunderstood anything. So I would say you could close your own question with that comment

Answer (score 2):

As I've commented, it looks like a known issue:

https://github.com/asyncapi/html-template/issues/11